# REST api call getting truncated

Tags: swift

I am doing an api rest call, but my response is getting truncated meanwhile in postman it seems ok

```
  APIClient.clientData { (result) in

        switch result {

        case .success(let response):
            #if DEBUG
            NSLog("response \(response)")
            #endif
            if response.isOK() {
                
                completion(Result.success(response))
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            #if DEBUG
            NSLog("error \(error.localizedDescription)")
            #endif
            break
        }
    }
```

Console:

response {"status":"OK","url_streaming":"hiddenlink","url_facebook_live":"hiddenlink","url_

Postman:

{
"status": "OK",
"url_streaming": "hiddenlink",
"url_facebook_live": "hiddenlink",
"url_anuncio": "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"
}

Anyone knows why the "url_anuncio" is getting truncated?

(i have like 40 more rows in the call but i deleted them in this question)

Comment: Are you seeing this after debugging the code or just by logging?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson after debugging whit NSLog("response \(response)") , and if i check that variable it is nil

Comment: Then how can it print anything?

Answer (score 0):

i forgot to decode the "url_anuncio" like the others, now is works good

```
urlAnuncio = try container.decode(String?.self, forKey: .urlAnuncio)
```

the text is still truncated in the debug console, idk if it have a character limit or something